# R - How to set the path of install.packages() for shiny server ? - Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

For my system: **Ubuntu 12.04** and **R 3.03**, whenever I install a custom package in **R** via

```
>install.packages()
```

the package is installed by default to

```
/home/USER/R/x86_64-pc-linus-gnu-library/3.0/
```

as opposed to system-wide in

```
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/
```

which is needed for **shiny-server** to work with that package.

My temporary solution is to copy the packages to the correct folder after the fact.

**Question: How can I set the default install path from the start to avoid this problem?**

Comment: Easiest way is usually to login as root (`sudo -i`), open R, and install it there. Then the package will be site-wide.

Comment: Not sure I can that easiest :)

Comment: // , Do you think this is relevant to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047690/how-do-i-install-packagesrsconnect-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes --  I consider this to be a misfeature and disable my per-user directory.

Moreover, I mostly use a script `install.r` (of which a version is an example in the littler package you can install as part of Ubuntu) which simple explicitly set the `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` directory as the default.   With a patch we got into R 3.0.2 or 3.0.3, normal user can write into the directory and will now create group-writeable directories so other users can update and overwrite -- just make everybody a member of the same group, say `staff` or `admin`.  And then you don't even need `sudo` or root.

I have essentially answered this same question a few times here over the years (minus the shiny angle, which is not really relevant) so feel free to search for the other for more details, examples, ...

Comment: Thanks, I can figure it out from there. I'll look again for a similar question - I had no luck on my first bunch of searches for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a different approach.

The problem is that shiny-server cannot find the packages that you install because it runs them as a different user which is called `shiny`. This user is created upon installation of shiny-server

The easiest (and safest IMHO) way to solve this is to just install the packages as the shiny user, using the following steps.

1. Set a password for the user using `sudo passwd shiny`, now enter and confirm a password of your choosing.
2. Switch to the shiny account using: `su - shiny`
3. Call up `R` using `$ R` (without sudo)
4. Install the required packages, in this case: `install.packages("shinydashboard")

Note that if you have rstudio-server installed on the same machine  then you can perform steps 2-4 using that interface. Simply go the same domain/ip and use :8787 for the rstudio-server interface instead of :3838 for shiny-server.

Adapted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32996405/1328355)

Comment: I cannot login using `shiny` account in the R studio server terminal. I did set password.

Comment: yeah I cannot seem to login either since a certain version. I have not idea what the problem is with that