# Change default Install location in R Studio in Ubuntu

Tags: r, shiny

I installed shiny using system wide installation method. So it is now at /usr/local/lib/R/site-library . And I'm using R Studio to install other packages such as RMySQL, ShinyBS etc. Those packages are located in /home/thisa/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0 . Now when I run my server.R with following libraries,

```
library("shinyBS", lib.loc="/home/thisa/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0")
```

It pops up following error.

```
ERROR: no library trees found in 'lib.loc'
```

What would be the possible solution for this should I change my default install directory of R Studio then how can I do that? I found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703595/r-how-to-set-the-path-of-install-packages-for-shiny-server-ubuntu) but the answer is not clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I truly dislike local installations below `$HOME` for that very reason.

Do this:

1. In R, do `.libPaths()` which will show the set of library directories known to R. Packages will go into the first of these.
2. On my system, I only get `"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"`, `"/usr/lib/R/site-library"`
   and `"/usr/lib/R/library"`
3. I am explicitly setting (in `/etc/R/Renviron`) `R_LIBS_SITE` to be 
   `${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library'}` which excludes the user library.
4. I may have had to override a default in RStudio as well but I don't see right now where that has been.  You can of course check by looking at `.libPaths()` as per 1. above.

In short, if you get the result I show in 2. then your libraries will all end up in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` and be visible to all instances, including Shiny apps.

Answer (score 0):

For me I followed the steps listed above by @Dirk and I had to perform one extra step.
Adding the user to the `staff` group.

In the terminal run.

```
sudo usermod -a -G staff user_name
```

Replace user_name with your user name. After restart and login in again. You should be able to install packages system-wide.