# R shinyapp deploy error: Error :An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification

Tags: r, shiny

I want to start shiny with shinyapps, but it errors.

```
==========================================================
ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
==========================================================
```

I used ui.R and server.R, 
R shiny App is working locally, but not on `shainyapps.io`.

I imported csv file in Korean, but I think that's not the problem about encoding.

Using packages in the code,

```
install.packages('leaflet')
install.packages('shiny')
install.packages('devtools')
install.packages('data.table')
install.packages("taRifx")
install.packages('tmap')
install.packages("wordcloud")
install.packages("treemap")
devtools::install_github("cardiomoon/Kormaps")
```

I checked the logs on my shinyapps.io pages, 
[image]

```
2018-01-31T04:05:04.194080+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2018-01-31T04:05:04.194107+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: R version: 3.4.2
2018-01-31T04:05:04.194108+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: shiny version: 1.0.5
2018-01-31T04:05:04.194109+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: rmarkdown version: NA
2018-01-31T04:05:04.406970+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: 
2018-01-31T04:05:04.406973+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: Starting R with process ID: '17'
2018-01-31T04:05:04.194109+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: knitr version: NA
2018-01-31T04:05:04.194110+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: jsonlite version: 1.5
2018-01-31T04:05:04.194111+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: RJSONIO version: NA
2018-01-31T04:05:04.194111+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: htmltools version: 0.3.6
2018-01-31T04:05:04.336879+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2018-01-31T04:05:04.438977+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: 
2018-01-31T04:05:04.438980+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:43727
2018-01-31T04:06:24.907597+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: Loading required package: leaflet
2018-01-31T04:06:24.908206+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
2018-01-31T04:06:24.908240+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:   there is no package called ‘leaflet’
2018-01-31T04:06:24.923741+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: Warning: Error in leafletOutput: could not find function "leafletOutput"
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927738+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927740+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     71: tag
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927749+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     61: div
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927755+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     53: fluidPage
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927742+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     70: tags$div
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927750+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     60: fluidRow
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927758+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     11: doTryCatch
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927743+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     69: div
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927751+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     59: tag
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927759+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:      9: tryCatchList
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927745+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     66: tags$div
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927751+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     58: tags$div
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927759+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     10: tryCatchOne
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927746+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     65: div
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927752+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     57: div
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927760+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:      8: tryCatch
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927747+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     64: column
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927753+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     56: tagList
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927761+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:      7: connect$retry
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927747+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     63: tag
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927754+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     55: attachDependencies
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927761+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:      6: eval
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927748+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     62: tags$div
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927755+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     54: bootstrapPage
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927762+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:      5: eval
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927743+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     68: wellPanel
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927756+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     13: runApp
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927764+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:      3: eval
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927744+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     67: tag
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927757+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:     12: fn
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927765+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:      2: eval.parent
2018-01-31T04:06:24.928105+00:00 shinyapps[259537]: Error : An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927763+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:      4: eval
2018-01-31T04:06:24.927765+00:00 shinyapps[259537]:      1: local
```

I guess it means package problem... but I don't know how to control this.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

From the image that you attatched, it shows that there is no package called leaflet.
[RStudio Shiny ERROR: there is no package called "shinydashboard"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794261/rstudio-shiny-error-there-is-no-package-called-shinydashboard)

Similar issue has been addressed check the link.

Comment: i think it's diffrent problem, i use shinyapps.io and windows7, but solution in the link is for shiny-server & linux user....... how do i applicate that???

Comment: it seems to be a problem with installing leaflet. Be sure to do individual library calls for each package instead of using lapply or similar.