# Loading required package: Sim.DiffProc Error in loadNamespace

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install `Sim.Diffproc` package in RStudio.  However, no matter how I install it (manually by writing or picking from the package list), the package does not work and produces this error:

> Loading required package: Sim.DiffProc Error in loadNamespace(i,
>   c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :    there is no
>   package called ‘shiny’

Do you know the how to fix this error ?

Comment: Have you tried searching after the missing package "shiny"?

Comment: run `library(shiny)` and see if you get an error

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794261/rstudio-shiny-error-there-is-no-package-called-shinydashboard) SO question helps

Comment: Yes I did try to install shiny then call it. But, even after I install shiny, when I write library only 3 things appear as shinybs, shinydashboard,shinyjs which is the same result as before installing shiny.